# Makefile g++ compile with -D variable from command line with default value

Tags: c++, makefile

I'm trying to setup a makefile which will take a command line argument and pass it on to the compiler with the -D flag. Also, set a default value for the variable.

e.g.

```
$: Make program FOO=12
```

and this will compile with `-DFOO=12`

Also, if `FOO` is not given at the command line how can I set a default value?  I am working with c++ so I can do

```
#ifndef FOO 

#define FOO 12

#endif
```

But I would like a way to have a default value inside the makefile.

Comment: You can do the code you suggest at the end, without the backslashes

Comment: You can reference environment variables in a makefile with `${VARNAME}`, so you'd want to have the caller specify the environment variable e.g. `MYDEFS="-DFOO=12" make`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ifeq ($(FOO),)         # check if FOO is not defined
CFLAGS= -DFOO=999      # if not defined, set a default value
else
CFLAGS= -DFOO=$(FOO)   # or use the value from argument
endif
```

Comment: Please add also some explanation in English

Answer (score 0):

Redefined macro is a warning, so if you aren't care about warnings, just add the default value into the flags, and append the user input one next, it will cover the default value.

If you don't like warnings, use `-U` argument.

```
-D FOO=1 -U FOO -D FOO=2
```